# Netbeans PHP getter/setter customization

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans for PHP code. When I use the generator for getter and setter methods in a class, the functions are named

```
get_something()
set_something()
```

How can I generate the functions in the camel case:

```
getSomething()
setSomething()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Netbeans are you using?

In 6.9 if you go `Source -> Insert Code -> Getter.../Setter...` there is a drop-down selection for Method Name.  In there you can select either camel case or using underscores.

Comment: This does not exist on newer versions of NetBeans (at least since 8.0.2, which I have, but pretty sure they had removed it a while ago).